# Cabal Update and Package Installation Errors

Tags: haskell, ghc, cabal, cabal-install

When I do `cabal install criterion`

I get the following error regarding the package `vector-algorithms`

```
Warning: The package list for 'hackage.haskell.org' is 16 days old.
Run 'cabal update' to get the latest list of available packages.
Resolving dependencies...
Downloading vector-algorithms-0.4...
cabal: Error: some packages failed to install:
vector-algorithms-0.4 failed while downloading the package. The exception was:
connect: does not exist (Connection refused)
```

And when I run `cabal update` it again errors with

```
Downloading the latest package list from hackage.haskell.org
cabal: openTCPConnection: host lookup failure for ""
```

What is wrong?

I'm using Ubuntu 11.10 and GHC 7.0.4 from [this PPA](https://launchpad.net/~mbeloborodiy/+archive/haskell-build) and my network connection is just fine in the rest of the system.

Comment: Can you check your cabal config?  In the file `~/.cabal/config`, look for a line beginning with `remote-repo:`, it should be `remote-repo: hackage.haskell.org:http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive`.

Comment: And then try ping'ing hackage.haskell.org to make sure it isn't a network issue.

Answer (score 4):

It was a proxy setting. It didn't suffice to unset `ftp_proxy` or `http_proxy` but also `https_proxy`. GNOME doesn't automatically remove terminal proxy configuraition when I disable it from system settings. Very annoying. I will write a shell-script that *disables all proxy* settings.

Sorry for bothering you all.

Comment: Not a bother. you helped me because I did the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

You may also force the proxy:

```
export http_proxy=hackage.haskell.org:80
cabal update
export http_proxy=
```